# After matching, "back up" a bit before restarting search

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to execute a global search on the following:

> \n123 abc\nmulti-lines \n234 xyz \n567 pqr \n422 abcdef \n999 eof

My intention is to return from the above:

```
123 abc
multi-lines

234 xyz

567 pqr

422 abcdef
```

My regex is "(?s)\n(\d{1,3}.*?)\d". However, the digit that is used as the end delimiter is "consumed" in a match and is not used as the start delimiter of the next match. As a result, I am getting only alternate groups for the result:

```
123 abc
multi-lines

567 pqr
```

Is there a regular expression that can achieve what I need?

I can do a first pass to modify the source to add a special delimiter character before every number, but is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Are you using a programming language here?

Comment: C# in PowerShell, but can switch to Node if that is "better". I am cobbling a script to process some raw data.

Comment: Like this? `(?s)(\n\d{1,3}.*?)(?=\n\d|$)` https://regex101.com/r/mLMzZP/1 Or like this `(?s)\n\d.*?(?=\n\d|$)` and replace with the whole match and a newline https://regex101.com/r/v5wKhb/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird  Lookahead it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the start with 1 to 3 digits, you would have to use a boundary after it, or else you can just start with match with the single digit.

Then you can assert either a newline followed by a digit, or the end of the string.

If the replacement use the full match followed by a newline.

Note that if you want to match a digit 0-9 in C# you can use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` which will match any digit.

```
(?s)\r?\n\d{1,3}\b.*?(?=\r?\n\d|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LULLZ3/1)

Or in Javascript with a match only, where `[^]*?` matches any character including a newline:

```
\n\d{1,3}\b[^]*?(?=\n\d|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/u3sM5s/1)

```js
const regex = /\n\d{1,3}\b[^]*?(?=\n\d|$)/g;
const str = `
123 abc
multi-lines 
234 xyz 
567 pqr 
422 abcdef 
999`;
const result = str.replace(regex, `$&\n`);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. My input is actually more complex and I had reduced it for the purpose of the question. The feature I needed was `lookahead`, which didn't come up when I tried various Google queries.